# Recover access to Samsung Galaxy Tab A after forgetting the pattern lock

Tags: pattern-lock, samsung-galaxy-tab-a

I have Samsung Galaxy Tab A and I put a pattern lock on it, but sometime later, I forgot the pattern.

I've looked it up and the only options to recover are to have the tablet off, but I can't turn the tablet off without the passcode.

How to recover access to it?

Answer (score 1):

Push the down volume button and power button at the same time. It reset my tablet and I just reentered the pattern and it worked. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple way out.

Assuming your tablet is connected to the Internet and you have Google account signed in, just enter pattern several times till the screen shows **Forgot pattern**. Click it then enter your Google account credentials to gain access to your tablet.

Answer (score 0):

Drain the battery down if you can't shut it down. Then, volume up and power for a few seconds (until it shows its doing something) from there, you can wipe the device

Answer (score 0):

Hold down the power button. Wait for the power off and restart to appear on the screen. You should see a restart in safe mode. Restart and if everything is ok do a regular restart 
I didn't forget my pattern but it wouldn't work. Just blanked the screen if I put in the correct pattern. And said incorrect pattern if I tried an incorrect pattern. I also noticed it was not counting down the incorrect attempts.
I did the above combo just by trying combos. It worked.
Good Luck

Comment: Can't shut it off without entering the pin...